# Java "Connection refused" error message on Linux, not on Windows

Tags: java, windows, ubuntu, connection

I have been testing the following program both on Linux and Windows. On Windows this works correctly, but on Linux (Ubuntu) this will stop randomly with a "Connection refused" exception.

What may be the reason for the connection problems? I'm trying to connect to a receipt printer and for example using telnet to the IP address works also.

Could there be a bug in JRE for Linux or is there something that could be changed with sysctl (TCP parameters)?

```
//java socket client example
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class socket_client
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {

 int i = 1;
while (i < 100) {

        Socket s = new Socket();
        s.setReuseAddress(true);
    String host = "10.0.10.71";
    PrintWriter s_out = null;

        try 
        {
        s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host , 9100));
        System.out.println("Connected");

        //writer for socket
            //s_out = new PrintWriter( s.getOutputStream(), true);
        }

        //Host not found
        catch (UnknownHostException e) 
        {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host : " + host);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        //Send message to server
    String message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
    //s_out.println( message );
s.close();
    System.out.println(s.isClosed());

    System.out.println("Message send");
i++;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: check if the port 9100 is not already in use on your linux session

Comment: The port 9100 is the port of the receipt printer at address 10.0.10.71.

Comment: One thing I have noticed, that if I put a `Thread.sleep(2); ` in the while loop, then it works correctly, but the question is why? Is the problem with the receipt printer, TCP/IP in Linux or what may be the reason? In Windows this test code works correctly when connecting to the printer.